# JavaScript - Deleting multiple identical values between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, compare

I'm currently working on a code where I need to compare two arrays and remove multiple elements with the same name. Here are the arrays;

```
vacant = [
"FRAMIA420.2 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 1h 36 m",
"FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 2h 36 m"]

booked = [
"FRAMIA440.5 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA540.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 5h 45 m",
"FRAMIA250.1 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA420.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA540.1 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA520.5 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA240.4 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA510.2 - 7h 0 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.1 - 1h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 2h 0 m"]
```

So the similar elements between these two arrays are: **FRAMIA420.2,** **FRAMIA510.4,** **FRAMIA520.7,** **FRAMIA450.3** and **FRAMIA340.2**

I've already filtered out the timestamp part of an element, so I would only need to compare the name parts;

```
var firstPart = [];
vacant.forEach(function (obj1) {
    firstPart.push(obj1.substring(0, obj1.indexOf('-')))
});
booked.forEach(function (obj2) {
    var c = firstPart.indexOf(obj2.substring(0, obj2.indexOf('-')));
});
```

The final result should look like this, only leaving the elements inside the `vacant` -array, that had no similarities with the `booked` -array:

```
FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m
FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m
FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m
```

Note that the similarities between the arrays varies everyday, sometimes there might be 2 similar elements and other days there might be 8 or more.

Any quick and effective way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a list of all names in the `booked` array, then iterate through the vacant array, checking for whether that name is in the list of booked names.

```js
vacant = [
  "FRAMIA420.2 - 0h 36 m",
  "FRAMIA510.4 - 0h 36 m",
  "FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m",
  "FRAMIA520.7 - 0h 36 m",
  "FRAMIA450.3 - 1h 36 m",
  "FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m",
  "FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m",
  "FRAMIA340.2 - 2h 36 m"
]

booked = [
  "FRAMIA440.5 - 13h 0 m",
  "FRAMIA540.2 - 3h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA340.2 - 5h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA250.1 - 3h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA420.2 - 3h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA540.1 - 13h 0 m",
  "FRAMIA520.5 - 3h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA240.4 - 3h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA510.2 - 7h 0 m",
  "FRAMIA510.4 - 2h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA520.7 - 2h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA450.1 - 1h 45 m",
  "FRAMIA450.3 - 2h 0 m"
]

function getName(str) {
  return str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-'));
}

var bookedNames = [];
booked.forEach(function (bookedStr) {
  bookedNames.push(getName(bookedStr))
});

var uniqueVacant = [];
vacant.forEach(function (vacantStr) {
  var vacantName = getName(vacantStr);
  if (!bookedNames.includes(vacantName))
    uniqueVacant.push(vacantStr)
});
console.log(uniqueVacant);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 loops, one for each array, and compare the first part of the string of each array, like so:

```
vacant = [
"FRAMIA420.2 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 1h 36 m",
"FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 2h 36 m"]

booked = [
"FRAMIA440.5 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA540.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 5h 45 m",
"FRAMIA250.1 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA420.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA540.1 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA520.5 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA240.4 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA510.2 - 7h 0 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.1 - 1h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 2h 0 m"]

for(i=0;i<vacant.length;i++) {
    item1 = vacant[i].split('-')[0];
    for(j=0;j<booked.length;j++) {
        item2 = booked[j].split('-')[0];
        if(item1===item2) {
                console.log('item number '+i+' in vacant is the same as item number '+j+' in booked');
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/48hef0cz/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
var vacant = [
"FRAMIA420.2 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 1h 36 m",
"FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 2h 36 m"];

var booked = [
"FRAMIA440.5 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA540.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 5h 45 m",
"FRAMIA250.1 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA420.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA540.1 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA520.5 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA240.4 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA510.2 - 7h 0 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.1 - 1h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 2h 0 m"];

vacant = vacant.filter(function (element) {
  var roomName = element.split('-')[0];
  
  var index = booked.findIndex(function (booking) {
    return roomName === booking.split('-')[0];
  });
  
  return index == -1;
});

console.log(vacant);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to keep track of unique values.

```js
vacant = [
"FRAMIA420.2 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA320.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 0h 36 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 1h 36 m",
"FRAMIA350.1 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA210.2 - 2h 21 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 2h 36 m"]

booked = [
"FRAMIA440.5 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA540.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA340.2 - 5h 45 m",
"FRAMIA250.1 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA420.2 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA540.1 - 13h 0 m",
"FRAMIA520.5 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA240.4 - 3h 45 m",
"FRAMIA510.2 - 7h 0 m",
"FRAMIA510.4 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA520.7 - 2h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.1 - 1h 45 m",
"FRAMIA450.3 - 2h 0 m"]

vacantDict = {};

vacant.forEach(function(val) {
  var name = val.split(' - ')[0];
  vacantDict[name] = val;
});

booked.forEach(function(val) {
  var name = val.split(' - ')[0];
  if (vacantDict[name] !== undefined) {
    delete vacantDict[name];
  }
});

newVacantList = [];
for (var name in vacantDict) {
  newVacantList.push(vacantDict[name]);
}

console.log(newVacantList);
```